# when I type in python bot.py the command wont execute

Tags: python, shellexecute

So I am attempting to code a discord bot and when I go to execute the command "python bot.py" the command comes up blank and doesn't execute the command. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{'The Ban Hammer has connected to Discord!'})

client.run(TOKEN)
```

```
#.env
DISCORD_TOKEN={Discord Token}
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.getenv` takes a string, the name of the environmental variable to lookup, not the value of the variable. You should use:

```
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```

and below

```
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Of course you should use a different private token, as the one you just posted is now public information on this website.

Also

```
f'{The Ban Hammer} has connected to Discord!'
```

is probably meant to be

```
'The Ban Hammer has connected to Discord!'
```

As the inside of the curly braces needs to be valid code.

Comment: ok thank you! Where would you put the actual token though?

Comment: The actual token would go in a file name `.env` as you had it. The `load_dotenv` you are using assumes this.

Comment: I edited the main post above. Is this correct because it still doesn't work

Comment: In the .env file, make sure you dont include the curly braces in the token. If this doesn't solve your issue, what error are you getting? DISCORD_TOKEN=ETCNOCURLYBRACES